# reading all files from HDFS recursively in spark java api

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark

I 'm using spark to read data of all files from HDFS in a single RDD from a directory and it's sub directories as well. I could not find any efficient method to do that. So I tried to write some customized code as shown below:

```
public Object fetch(String source,String sink) {

    //reading data
    boolean isDir=new File(source).isDirectory();
    System.out.println("isDir="+isDir);
    JavaRDD<String> lines;
    if(isDir)
    {

        lines=readFiles(new File(source).listFiles(), null);
    }
    else
        lines= sc.textFile(source);

    lines.saveAsTextFile(sink);
    return true;
}

public static JavaRDD<String> readFiles(File[] files,JavaRDD<String> lines) {
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            readFiles(file.listFiles(),lines); // Calls same method again.
        } 
        else {
            if(lines==null)
                lines=sc.textFile(file.getPath());
            else
            {
                JavaRDD<String> r=sc.textFile(file.getPath());
                lines.union(r);
            }
        }
    }
    return lines;
}
```

but this is not doing my expected job as isDir contains false telling that it's not a directory.
Please can u guide me about what's wrong? and is there some efficient way to do this job?
Thanks alot

Comment: I'm not sure, but you should be using `Path` api instead of `File`

Comment: yep, I was at mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As spark can read data based on a Hadoop Job configuration, you can use the `FileInputFormat#setInputDirRecursive` method.

```
JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext();

Job job;

try {
  job = Job.getInstance();
  FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("/path/to/input/directory));
  FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);
} catch (IOException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
  System.exit(1);
}

JavaRDD<Text> sourceData = context.newAPIHadoopRDD(job.getConfiguration(), TextInputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class)
  .values();
```

Obviously you will end up with a Text data type instead of a String.

Answer (score 2):

the "*" character reads the folder recursively

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
sc.textFile("/my/directory/*");
```

read this link for more info:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#external-datasets

Comment: So much simpler than the other answers, I don't know why this is not the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

so finally I found a solution. I was at mistake as I was using object of File that is used for reading files from local file system. In order to read/write to HDFS we need to use org.apache.hadoop.fs.*

so here is the solution

```
public Object fetch(String source,String sink) {

    //reading data
    Path src=new Path(source);
    try {
        if(fs.exists(src))
        {
            FileStatus[] lists=fs.listStatus(src);
            readFiles(lists);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}

public void readFiles(FileStatus[] files) {
        for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
        {
            if(files[i].isDirectory())
            {
                try {
                    readFiles(fs.listStatus(files[i].getPath()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                    if(lines==null)
                    {
                       Path p=files[i].getPath();
                       JavaRDD<String> lines=sc.textFile(p.toString());
                    }
                    else
                   {
                      JavaRDD<String> r=sc.textFile(file.getPath());
                      lines.union(r);
                   }
        }
  }
  return lines;
 }
```