# How to recursively read Hadoop files from directory using Spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Inside the given directory I have many different folders and inside each folder I have Hadoop files (`part_001`, etc.).

```
directory
   -> folder1
      -> part_001...
      -> part_002...
   -> folder2
      -> part_001...
   ...
```

Given the directory, how can I recursively read the content of all folders inside this directory and load this content into a single RDD in Spark using Scala?

I found this, but it does not recursively enters into sub-folders (I am using `import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input`):

```
  var job: Job = null
  try {
    job = Job.getInstance()
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("s3n://" + bucketNameData + "/" + directoryS3))
    FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true)
  } catch {
    case ioe: IOException => ioe.printStackTrace(); System.exit(1);
  }
  val sourceData = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(job.getConfiguration(), classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text]).values
```

I also found this [web-page](http://rajkrrsingh.blogspot.com.es/2015/10/apache-spark-reading-and-writing.html) that uses `SequenceFile`, but again I don't understand how to apply it to my case?

Comment: have you tried with a simple wildcard? If the directory structure  is consistent, it should work like a charm

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27843858/647053

Comment: @Chobeat: Do you mean that the answer of dbustosp (`var rdd = sc.textFile("path/*/*")`) will directly do what I explained  without the need to write all the code that I posted?

Comment: Remember that if you are writing a Java program for doing that, you will need to instance SparkContext (sc) by yourself. In the spark-shell it automatically instance. A good practice is to use spark-shell to test the code and make sure the code is doing what you expect.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using Spark, you can do this using wilcards as follow:

```
scala>sc.textFile("path/*/*")
```

**sc** is the SparkContext which if you are using spark-shell is initialized by default or if you are creating your own program should will have to instance a SparkContext by yourself.

Be careful with the following flag:

```
scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.get("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive") 
> res6: String = null
```

Yo should set this flag to true:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true")
```

Comment: So, do you mean that I can simply do this? `val myRDD = sc.textFile("path/*/*")`? No need to use `setInputDirRecursive`? Will I get RDD of String? (I need RDD of String)

Comment: Yes, exactly right. This will be loaded as String by default and if you use wildcards you will not use that flag.

Comment: Ok, one more thing that I misunderstand: if the data in Hadoop files has JSON format, I will get RDD of JSON strings after doing `sc.textFile(...)`, right? Then, to convert it into DataFrame will this approach work?: `val rddFromHadoop = sc.textFile("path/*/*")   import sqlContext.implicits._
      var df = rddFromHadoop.toDF()`. Or should I parse `rddFromHadoop` to`RDD[Map[String,String]]` before applying `toDF()`? Sorry, for this additional question. It's just important for me to understand that my overall approach will work if I use `textFile` and read hadoopish files into RDD.

Comment: That's a different use case. You should use SqlContext instead, this class contains support for reading json files. Take a look at: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/02/an-introduction-to-json-support-in-spark-sql.html

Comment: Ah, wait, do you mean this?: `var df = sqlContext.read.json("path/*/*")`, assuming that I have hadoopish data inside sub-folders, but these hadoopish data was saved from RDD of JSON strings (`rdd.saveAsTextFile(filePath)`). If so, that's actually great.

Comment: Yup. Also see: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html#jsonFile%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: `sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive", "true")` works in pyspark!

Answer (score 5):

I have found that the parameters must be set in this way:

```
.set("spark.hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories","true")
.set("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
connector_output=${basepath}/output/connector/*/*/*/*/*
```

works for me when I've dir structure like -

```
${basepath}/output/connector/2019/01/23/23/output*.dat
```

I didn't have to set any other properties, just used following -

```
sparkSession.read().format("csv").schema(schema)
                    .option("delimiter", "|")
                    .load("/user/user1/output/connector/*/*/*/*/*");
```