# Ignore empty folders when reading with Spark wholeTextFiles

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I'm using wholeTextFiles to read a bunch of xml files from different folders and some of these folders might be empty. Unfortunately Spark throws an exception if any of these folders are empty:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input Pattern file:/path/*/*/*.xml matches 0 files
```

I've seen some ways of workaround this issue when dealing with regular RDDs, like [this one](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Ignoring-S3-0-files-exception-td6101.html), but I couldn't find anything similar when using wholeTextFiles.

I've looked a bit into Spark code and this method uses a bunch of private classes, so it seems hard to change the behaviour. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of using wildcards, consider using Hadoop configuration.

Comment: What do you mean by using Hadoop configuration instead of wildcards?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48174564/6910411